# Scrollable list bounces back to top[iScroll], rubber band effect?

Tags: android, html, cordova

Developing an android app in html5(phonegap) and I had to use a scrollView. Could find anything in html5 as we have in Java so I'm trying to use the library `iScroll` which served the purpose of scrolling but as I scroll down it bounces back to top, I suppose it is called rubber-band-effect. How do I handle this glitch? Plus as I scroll down by dragging I get a warning in Logcat:

```
 W/webview(2795): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.
```

Check my following code in which the list items are getting dynamically added which should not be the issue, the problem IMO lies in html itself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Storage Example </title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexCss.css" />
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
    body,ul,li {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        border:0;
    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" >
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <header>
 <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="enter name" />
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick='Add();' />
</header>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="scroll-content">

<div id="result"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer>
    Some Footer Content 
</footer>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="iscroll.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

var theScroll;
function scroll() {
    theScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', scroll, true);



</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
scroll = new iScroll(this, {
    useTransform: false,
    useTransition: true
});
```

If does not work, go through this:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/iscroll/CMB9d_e5d4Y

Comment: It was same, I switched from lite to this version.

Comment: Could you please post the html from your browser (save page as).

Comment: its the same code as I posted in my question, I'm losing faith in html5 now and will be switching back to native.

Comment: I replicated your environment on Chrome browser. I am not able to see the behavior you mentioned. Is the problem only on mobile device.

Comment: Yes! I am developing specially for mobiles.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check

Comment: You may want to try modifying your css by just keeping minimum div sizing information and remove all the rest. It should work, if you follow the hints given in the google group link, I posted above.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem solved, removing the `height:100%;` property from my wrapper.

`bottom:0;` made sure the wrapper stretched all the way to the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when you have a `container` div for your `wrapper` The fix for this is to set the height of the `container` to `99%`.

Following is the CSS which finally fixed this issue for me:

```
#productsScreen{ /* my container */
    height: 99%;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
#productListWrapper{
    background:transparent;
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:1;
    top: 88px;
    bottom:49px; 
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
#productsListScroller {
    position:absolute; z-index:1;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and after sweet midnight debugging fount that my wrapper was resizing for some reason to height way bigger than the phone screen. Im using jquery mobile paging and somehow it was messing with the iScroll. Here is how i solved it:

**HTML**

```
<div id="screen" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="list-wrapper">
            <ul>
            ...
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
// the iScroll should be initialized after the page is visible 
// to prevent bug with display:none. If you are not using
// jQuery mobile paging this can be skipped.
$('#screen').on('pageshow', function() {

    // calculate the expected height of the real content wrapper and set it         
    var screenHeight = $('#screen').height();
    var footerHeight = $('#screen [data-role="footer"]').height();
    var realContentHeight = screenHeight - footerHeight;
    $('#list-wrapper').css({'height': realContentHeight + 'px'});

    // create or refresh the iScroll after resizing the wrapper         
    if (myScrollFunction != null ) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            myScrollFunction .refresh();
        }, 100);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            myScrollFunction  = new iScroll('list-wrapper');
        }, 100);
    }
});
```