# iScroll for Multipages

Tags: html, cordova, iscroll, iscroll4

i'm doing phonegap project with html5-css-js.

on this project, i use iscroll swipe for swipe gesture issue between pages.

on my first page, my iscroll works and scrolling down all page.

But when  i swipe my second page, my second page looks static. It doesnt go bottom and doesnt show the data, doesnt move.

Here is the code i use;

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="frame">

        <div id="pageWrapper">

            <div id="pageScroller">

                <div class="page" >
                    <div id="wrapper">
                        <div class="scroller">
                            <h1>Canlı Skorlar</h1>
                            <hr/>
                            <table border="1">
                                <tr>
                                    <td rowspan="2" width="15%" align="center"> data1 </td> 
                                    <td width="85%"> data2</td>
                                    <td> data3 </td>
                                </tr> 
                                <tr> 
                                    <td> data4 </td> 
                                    <td> data5</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="page" >
                    <div id="wrapper">
                        <div class="scroller">
                            <h1>Canlı Skorlar</h1>
                            <hr/>
                            <table border="1">
                                <tr>
                                    <td rowspan="2" width="15%" align="center"> data1 </td> 
                                    <td width="85%"> data2</td>
                                    <td> data3 </td>
                                </tr> 
                                <tr> 
                                    <td> data4 </td> 
                                    <td> data5</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="page" >
                    <div id="wrapper">
                        <div class="scroller">
                            <h1>Canlı Skorlar</h1>
                            <hr/>
                            <table border="1">
                                <tr>
                                    <td rowspan="2" width="15%" align="center"> data1 </td> 
                                    <td width="85%"> data2</td>
                                    <td> data3 </td>
                                </tr> 
                                <tr> 
                                    <td> data4 </td> 
                                    <td> data5</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="page" >
                    <div id="wrapper">
                        <div class="scroller">
                            <h1>Canlı Skorlar</h1>
                            <hr/>
                            <table border="1">
                                <tr>
                                    <td rowspan="2" width="15%" align="center"> data1 </td> 
                                    <td width="85%"> data2</td>
                                    <td> data3 </td>
                                </tr> 
                                <tr> 
                                    <td> data4 </td> 
                                    <td> data5</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/iscroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/scroll.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Anyone can tell me how can i get rid of this problem ?

Thanks.

**UPDATE :** scroll.js

```
document.addEventListener("orientationchange", updateLayout);

// The wrapperWidth before orientationChange. Used to identify the current page number in updateLayout();
wrapperWidth = 0;

var myScroll = new iScroll('pageWrapper', {
    snap: true,
    momentum: false,
    hScrollbar: false,
    vScrollbar: false,
    lockDirection: true});

updateLayout();

function updateLayout() {

    var currentPage = 0;

    if (wrapperWidth > 0) {
        currentPage = - Math.ceil( $('#pageScroller').position().left / wrapperWidth);
    }

    wrapperWidth = $('#pageWrapper').width();

    $('#pageScroller').css('width', wrapperWidth * 4);
    $('.page').css('width', wrapperWidth - 40);
    myScroll.refresh();
    myScroll.scrollToPage(currentPage, 0, 0);
}

page3Scroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {hScrollbar: false, vScrollbar: false, lockDirection: true });
```

and i couldnt put iscroll js because of limitations.

So, i didnt eat js folders.

So. Help please my friend.

Comment: Where is the JS part where you create (and possibly destroy) the iScroll?

Comment: i updated it mate. Can you check it please

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution on iscroll4 documentation.

"iScroll needs to be initialized for each scrolling area you need. There’s no limit to the number of iScrolls you can have on any single page, if not that imposed by the device memory/cpu. The type and length of the contents influence the number of iScrolls you can use simultaneously."

I hope it helps for someone.

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize/refresh the function after 'pageshow' event since iScroll has issues with *display:none* property.

Check my detail explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18726304/1959362

For example:

```
$('#<id-of-your-jqm-page>').on('pageshow', function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        myScrollFunction .refresh();
    }, 100);
});
```